# Tkinter button stuck on load

Tags: python, tkinter, button, loading

I created a version of the [Catchphrase game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8VNTTzQMK48&t=69s) with two tkinter buttons <kbd>Start</kbd> and <kbd>Next</kbd>. <kbd>Start</kbd> enables the timer and <kbd>Next</kbd> is supposed to display the next randomly generated phrase.

In the `tk` window, whenever I press <kbd>Start</kbd> the first time, it shows the loading icon, which does not let me press the <kbd>Next</kbd> button. What am I doing wrong? `:(`

```
from tkinter import *
import random

from playsound import playsound

BEEPER = ('catchphrase.mp3', 'catchphrase_26_sec.mp3', 'catchphrase_15_sec.mp3')


# create window with button
root = Tk ()
root.geometry ('400x400')

# random word generator
with open ("Catchphrase-Words.txt", "r") as file:
    allText = file.read ()
    words = list (map (str, allText.splitlines ()))
    # print random string
    print (random.choice (words))


# define timer function:
def timer():
    while playsound (random.choice (BEEPER)):
        button2["state"] = ACTIVE


# define myClick function:
def gen_phrase():
    label2.config (text=random.choice (words))


# create label
label = Label (root, text='''To earn points, make sure someone from your
team isn't caught holding the Catchphrase
game unit when the timer runs out!''', padx=50, pady=40)
label.pack ()

# create Start button
button1 = Button (root, text='Start', padx=10, pady=20)
button1.pack ()
button1.config (command=timer)
button1.config (font=('Ink Free', 20, 'bold'))
button1.config (activebackground='#fffb1f')
button1.config (fg='#50288C')

# Create Next button

button2 = Button (root, text='Next', padx=10, pady=20)
button2.pack ()
button2.config (command=gen_phrase)
button2.config (font=('Ink Free', 20, 'bold'))
button2.config (activebackground='#fffb1f')
button2.config (fg='#50288C')

# word generator in the window
label2 = Label (root, text=random.choice (words), padx=10, pady=10)
label2.config (font=('Monospace', 30, 'bold'))
label2.pack ()

root.mainloop ()
```

Comment: Your `timer()` function blocks because it has a `while` loop. Nothing will happen within the GUI until that function returns.

Comment: @quamrana Yes, I thought about it, but even if I try the `if` function, the "Next" button is still blocked.

Comment: But that is still calling `timer()` which blocks until it returns.

Comment: @quamrana what can I do to fix it?

Comment: @Ambar Try using a `.after` script. Creating a new thread might also work

Answer (score 0):

Okay fixed it, can't believe how simple it was. Shout out to @TheLizzard for the tip!

So,

1. import the *threading* package in Python
2. instead of just running the `timer()` command in <kbd>Start</kbd>:

> `button1.config (command=timer)` ,

create a new thread for the <kbd>Start</kbd> button and inside of that thread run the `timer()` function:

`button1.config (command=threading.Thread(target=timer).start())`

And that should make the <kbd>Start</kbd> button run independently, in parallel allowing us to click <kbd>Next</kbd> with no problems:)

Thanks to everyone who commented!

**Edit:**
To make the `timer()` function run only when the <kbd>Start</kbd> button is pressed, simply remove this line:

> button2["state"] = ACTIVE